# ggplot2 fill polygons in shapefile by coords

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

So i have shapefile (named [POWIATY](http://www.gauss.pl/analityk/drupal/node/43) at the bottom of the page). I want to fill the specific polygons by the coords I have.

Let's say, I want to fill whole region in:
lat:52.599427
lon:20.7572137

I know how to set point coords on the map but how to fill whole polygon in it?

Comment: I can't understand the question, Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: Is there a group or region (or some other term) defined in the shapefile for the region you want to color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are duplicate region names in that shapefile so you'll have to fill by polygon numeric id:

```
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)

pow <- readOGR("POWIATY.shp", "POWIATY")
plot(pow)

where <- over(SpatialPoints(cbind(20.7572137, 52.599427)), pow, TRUE)
reg <- data.frame(id=rownames(where[[1]]))

map <- fortify(pow)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=map, data=map, 
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="white", color="black", size=0.25)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=reg, map=map,
                    aes(fill=id, map_id=id), color="steelblue")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

Comment: I tested it for a while. When I try to add this to another shapefile it shows me
"variable identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE" after using over function.

Also when I try to use gps for all of the polygons in the map to fill it shows some blank spaces.

There is link to the shapefile:
[link](ftp://91.223.135.109/prng/PRNG_MIEJSCOWOSCI_SHP.zip)